# recreate_versions! using the unique filename method stated in the wiki

Tags: ruby, rubygems, carrierwave

I'm trying to use the `method recreate_versions!` but I'm using the method from the wiki to create unique filenames. The problem is that when I run `recreate_versions!` it changes the filenames but it doesn't update them on the mounted object itself. How could I refresh these URL's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what worked for me. It uses the filename if it already exists. So they don't change when you recreate_versions!

```
def filename
  if original_filename
    if model && model.read_attribute(:avatar).present? #or whatever you call your column
      model.read_attribute(:avatar)
    else
      # create new filename however you're doing it
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem is that the unique filename is usually meant to deal with files caching, doing so will still point to the same URL when doing a recreate_versions! and therefore return the cached value instead of the new one.

Answer (score 11):

A solution that works when dealing with caching is to save the mounted object after recreating versions:

Example:

```
avatar.image.recreate_versions!
avatar.save!
```

This way you can keep using unique filenames even when recreating versions and properly handle caching.